# including leading whitespaces when using fgets in php

Tags: php, text, str-replace, fgets

I am using PHP to read a simple text file with the `fgets()` command:

```
$file = fopen("filename.txt", "r") or exit('oops');
$data = "";

while(!feof($file)) {
    $data .= fgets($file) . '<br>';
}

fclose($file);
```

The text file has leading white spaces before the first character of each line. The `fgets()` is not grabbing the white spaces. Any idea why? I made sure **not** to use `trim()` on the variable. I tried this, but the leading white spaces still don't appear:

```
$data = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $data);
```

Not sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance,

Doug

**UPDATE:**

The text appears correctly if I dump it into a textarea but not if I ECHO it to the webpage.

Comment: What if you use other reading functions instead, like `fread()`?

Comment: Please try `file_get_contents` and tell us if there is still no whitespace.

Comment: I can't use FREAD because I don't know how long the line will be. The length parameter is required for FREAD.

Comment: FILE_GET_CONTENTS doesn't allow me to insert <BR> between lines. It grabs the whole file all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function fgets() grabs the whitespaces. I don't know what you are exactly doing with the $data variable, but if you simply display it on a HTML page then you won't see whitespaces. It's because HTML strips all whitespaces. Try this code to read and show your file content:

```
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'r') or exit('error'); 
$data = '';

while(!feof($file)) 
{
    $data .= '<pre>' . fgets($file) . '</pre><br>'; 
}

fclose($file);

echo $data;
```

The PRE tag allows you to display $data without parsing it.

Comment: using PRE adds extra line breaks, but doesn't include the leading white spaces.

Comment: I tried the above code a few minutes ago and there is no problem with fgets() function. It reads all whitespaces that occur in a line. Maybe it's a problem with encoding the file that you try to read?

Comment: did you try with blank spaces **before** the first character in the line? it works fine if the spaces come after the first character.

Comment: Yes. I've tried it once again just to make sure. I have whitespaces at the beginning of a line, in the middle and at the end (a few lines with different combinations). Someone posted a version with file_get_contents() function. It also works fine (it reads all the file at once but include whitespaces).

Comment: That is very odd. Maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: okay I think I figured it out. I had a TRIM applied to the FGETS variable. It was removing the leading whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
$data = preg_replace('/\s+/', '&nbsp;', $data);
```

`fgets` should not trim whitespaces.

Comment: using PREG_REPLACE removes the spaces between all of the characters, and doesn't include the leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the file using file_get_contents it is successfully reading the whitespace in the begining of the file.

`$data = file_get_contents("xyz.txt");`

`$data = str_replace(" ","~",$data);`

`echo $data;`

Hope this helps

Comment: this might work, if there was a way to identify the line breaks and replace them with a BR.

Comment: My actual meaning was asking you to check if your problem is solved by using the 1st line of the code.

Comment: negative. the leading white spaces are still excluded using the file_get_contents method.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the same requirement and experienced that some characters are written as a tab character.

What i did was:

```
$tabChar = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
$regularChar = '&nbsp;'

$file = fopen('/file.txt');
while($line = fgets($file)) {

   $l = str_replace("\t", $tabChar, $line);
   $l = str_replace(" ", $regularChar, $line);
   // ...
   // replacing can be done till it matches your needs

   $lines .= $l; // maybe append <br /> if neccessary

}

$result = '<pre'> . $lines . '</pre>';
```

This one worked for me, maybe it helps you too :-).